# Make google drive link change after customer paypal button purchase

Tags: paypal

How do I make google drive link change after customer paypal button purchase. So it's never the same link and no to be shared to someone who didn't pay for it?

Comment: Please be more specific in what you want to achieve

Comment: I would like to make my shared link from google drive that is embeded in paypal button function to change after purchase action, so after that download it is not accessible any more with that address but I would like it to be automatically changed to another link if possible or something similar so I can protect my shared file being accessed except with another purchase